# How to make desktops in Linux display in a multi-monitor environment?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xfce

I want to assign diferent desktops to different monitors.

Such as:

- desktop A displays on monitor A
- desktop B displays on monitor B
- …

My desktop environment is xfce. I have an NVIDIA GeForce GT 620M/630M.

Comment: How many monitors do you have? What graphics card? What desktop environment?

Comment: If you really want control over your workspaces on different screens, look into Xmonad. It's a tiling window manager; I mostly use it fullscreen with no desktop environment.